# Using multiple effects in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I started to play a little with firemonkey and it's effect. It works very well, but only one effect at a time. I've added a gloweffect and a reflection effect to a Label and it doesn't work as expected. If I add the effect both to the label only one will be applied. If I nest one effect into another, then strange things happen. The reflection within the glow results in only the glow, the glow in within the reflection inverts the y-axis of the reflection and recolors it.

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to get a glowing label with a reflection beneath?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use only one effect at time. try to add layout with reflection, then add label with glow

Comment: Thanks, this workaround does it :)

Comment: I have an XE5 firemonkey HD application with 2 TImages in a TScrollBox. one image has a TPerspectiveTransformEffect and a TGaussianBlurEffect on it and the other has a TColorKeyAlphaEffect in it to do a chroma key. the Scrollbox itself has a TCropEffect on it. If i disable the crop effect, all other effects work perfectly. If i enable the crop effect then only the perspective effect works. Any ideas?